# Why am I obtaining this error related the auto increment PK of a PosgreSQL table using Hibernate? ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Booot application using **Spring Data JPA**.
As database I am using PostgreSQL and I am finding some problem mapping an auto increment primary key field of a table to the related field of my entity class.

In my database I manually created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."user"
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    first_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    middle_name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    surname character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Please not that the **id** field (my PK) is defined as a **bigint** with the **GENERATED ALWAYS** constraint and not as a **serial** (this because serial data type is deprecated because it is not part of the SQL standard).

Then I created this entity class mapping this table:

```
package com.easydefi.users.entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Table(name = "portal_user")
@Data
public class User implements Serializable {
     
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5062673109048808267L;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;
    
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    
    public User(String firstName, String middleName, String surname, char sex, Date birthdate, String taxCode,
            String eMail, String contactNumber, Date createdAt) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    

}
```

Then I have this repository interface (at the moment it is empty because I am testing only the **save()** method directly provided by **JpaRepository**):

```
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Finnally I created this simple unit test method in order to test the insert of a new record via the **save()** method of my repository:

```
@SpringBootTest()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GetUserWsApplication.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository userRepository;
    
    
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void testInsertUser() {
        User user = new User("Mario", null, "Rossi", 'M', new Date(), "XXX", "xxx@gmail.com", "329123456", new Date());
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
    
}
```

the problem is that when the **save()** method is performed I am obtaining this exception:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        portal_user
        (first_name, middle_name, surname, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-11-04 12:17:39.576  WARN 11436 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 428C9
2021-11-04 12:17:39.578 ERROR 11436 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: cannot insert a non-DEFAULT value into column "id"
  Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS.
  Hint: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.
```

So I try to modify the mapping of the **id** field into my entity class, in this way:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

But running my test method now the **save()** method execution give me this other error:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2021-11-04 12:20:21.133  WARN 11639 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2021-11-04 12:20:21.136 ERROR 11639 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
  Position: 17
```

What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

To

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

Because `GenerationType.IDENTITY` create `primary key` with `auto increment` that is not modified manually.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine now. Only a further question: what do you meand that it automatically create this hibernate_sequence table? I cannot see this table into my DB. Where is it and what it should contains?

Comment: Remove previous table and run your `POJO` it will create new table with `hibernate_sequence`

Comment: And `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` is `HSQL` database syntex and you can use `SQL`

Comment: mmm I set my Spring Boot project in order to now allow Hibernate to create table. I prefear to manueally created them by myself, then mapping the table with the entity. It could be a problem? Why after this change is it working also if this "hibernate_sequence" table was not created? tnx

Comment: I don't have more knowledge about `postgresql` but why create table manually Spring Boot provide best facility to create table...

Comment: I am from the old school...I design my database with ER and phisical scheme, I normalize it. I don't like that Hibernate defines table for me...I prefear that it is Hibernate that adapt to my tables

Comment: Hmm, Very nice..

Answer (score 1):

The error is definitely on this line.

```
id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
```

If you want a quick fix, you can change it to the one below.
`SERIAL` works in Postgres just fine. Sure, it might not run on other databases, but how often does an IT project do a DB migration ? Never.

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

Does this solve your problem ? Or you somehow need to solve it without SERIAL for some reason ?